# aurelia skeleton-es2016 error

Tags: aurelia, browser-sync

I was following Aurelia tutorials. Specifically the production setup part

http://aurelia.io/docs.html#/aurelia/framework/1.0.0-beta.1.1.4/doc/article/a-production-setup

After nmp install and jspm install, gulp watch throws error:

```
module.js:327 throw error

Error: Cannot find module 'socket.io'
```

What's causing this?

It traces error to `...\browser-sync\lib\sockets.js:3:15`

Comment: Check your gulp watch windows you have an error or something

Comment: Ehhm im sorry, I'm not exactly sure what you mean. Concerning the error, it seemed to be caused by browser sync tough i checked and socket.io is present in the node modules folder

Comment: It seems that something hasn't been installed. Delete the npm_modules and jspm_packages folders. Then run `npm install` and `jspm install -y` again. Don't forget the `-y` after jspm install

Answer (score 1):

So I realized that socket.io was missing in the browser-sync dependencies. Had to run npm install in browser-sync folder. Also I was not aware of the fact that npm install will check only the root dependencies. If one of its dependencies is missing a dependency of its own, it won't tell you. You can run nmp ls to check for missing dependencies.